# no wifi adapter found, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Lenovo

Tags: drivers, 22.04, lenovo, iwlwifi

In my lenovo laptop wireless network is not working. I am getting `No wifi adapter found` error.

```
*-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:a1118000-a111bfff
```

Result of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    8.418262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    8.418291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    8.418297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    8.418300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    8.418302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    8.418305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    8.418307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    8.418310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    8.418313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    8.418316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    8.418318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    8.418321] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    8.418324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    8.418326] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    8.418329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    8.418332] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    8.418334] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    8.423510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.113173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x312
[   10.154777] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   10.154835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_ARC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x2f
[   10.154872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   10.154914] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   10.154940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x4
[   10.154963] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc0080000
[   10.154987] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x60920
[   10.154996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   10.402908] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   10.402949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   10.402953] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   10.402984] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   10.403004] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   10.403015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB33336FA | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   10.403027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   10.403040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAF1FEEF | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   10.403052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   10.403064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07184849 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   10.403076] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82209A59 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   10.403088] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8A6DFFFB | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   10.403100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x44622A04 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   10.403112] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.403156] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   10.403233] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   10.403311] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   10.403324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   10.403331] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   11.127110] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   11.140259] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
[   11.147878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x312
[   12.166754] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   12.166790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_ARC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x2f
[   12.166811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   12.166833] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   12.166854] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x4
[   12.166875] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc0080000
[   12.166896] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x60920
[   12.166900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   12.414771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   12.414795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   12.414798] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   12.414819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   12.414838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   12.414848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB33336FA | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   12.414859] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   12.414870] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAF1FEEF | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   12.414880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   12.414891] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07184849 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   12.414901] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82209A59 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   12.414912] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8A6DFFFB | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   12.414922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x44622A04 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   12.414932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.414975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   12.415051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   12.415127] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   12.415137] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   12.415142] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   13.095068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   13.107773] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
[   13.113939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x312
[   14.150763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[   14.150799] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_ARC1_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x2f
[   14.150821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: HPM_SECONDARY_DEVICE_STATE: 0x42
[   14.150842] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_ADDR: 0x0
[   14.150864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_MAC_OTP_CFG7_DATA: 0x4
[   14.150885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc0080000
[   14.150905] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x60920
[   14.150909] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   14.398810] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   14.398834] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   14.398837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
[   14.398858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM data1
[   14.398877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   14.398887] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB33336FA | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   14.398898] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   14.398909] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDAF1FEEF | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   14.398920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   14.398930] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x07184849 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   14.398941] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x82209A59 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   14.398951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8A6DFFFB | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   14.398962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x44622A04 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   14.398972] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   14.399015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   14.399090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   14.399166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   14.399177] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   14.399182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   15.080385] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   15.093161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 Updated.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555 No, It is single boot.

Comment: If you boot into an earlier kernel at the GRUB menu, does it work? What does this tell us: `sudo dpkg -s backport-iwlwifi-dkms | grep Status` Did the wireless work previously? Is this a fresh install?